# How to make DataTable.Compute work with different CultureInfos

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datatable, cultureinfo

I am trying to parse a basic math expression string, such as "2+2", so that users can put expressions into number boxes.

Here is my code

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = culture;
var result = table.Compute(expression, null);
value = (double)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(double), culture);
```

This works just fine when my culture is "en". If I put "2+0.2" into the number box, the code would output `2.2` as a double.

However, when my culture is something like "es-ES", which uses commas for decimals, the code doesn't work. If my expression is "2+0,2" it throws a SyntaxErrorException.

**STATUS UPDATE:**

I've implemented Darren Lee's workaround but it's not ideal. It'd be great if there was some built-in .NET method to handle expression parsing in different cultures.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-7.0#parsing-literal-expressions

Comment: All literal expressions must be expressed in the invariant culture locale. Extracted from the link above shared by ASh

Answer (score 3):

Edited Answer:

`var result = table.Compute(expression, null);`

The expression you passed in must be expressed in the invariant culture locale. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-7.0#parsing-literal-expressions

What you can do is to manually parse your expression to be invariant culture locale (if you really have to)

Implementation (You should probably test this thoroughly as I wrote it right off my mind):

```
    public static class Expression
    {
        private static char[] operators = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/', '%' };
        public static string Parse(string input, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var output = string.Empty;

            // find out the operators used in your raw expression
            // this is to reconstruct the output later
            var operatorsUsed = new List<char>();
            foreach (var c in input)
            {
               if (operators.Contains(c))
                {
                    operatorsUsed.Add(c);
                } 
            }

            var numbers = input.Split(operators);
            foreach (var number in numbers)
            {
                // parse your numbers to invariant culture locale
                output += double.Parse(number, cultureInfo).ToString();

                if (operatorsUsed.Count > 0)
                {
                    // add in the respective operator
                    output += operatorsUsed[0];
                    operatorsUsed.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    var result = table.Compute(Expression.Parse("2+0,2", table.Locale), null); //2.2
```

Original Answer:

I believe that commas are not valid in expressions. Not sure whether this will help you but it gets the expected result.

```
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    table.Columns.Add("x", typeof(double));
    table.Columns.Add("y", typeof(double));
    table.Columns.Add("result", typeof(double), "x + y");

    table.Rows.Add("2", "0,2");
    var result = table.Rows[0][2]; //2.2
```

Comment: I was worried I'd have to do something like that. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.